# How to give a Contextmenu to same tableview according to Action in javafx?

Tags: uitableview, javafx, combobox, tableview, contextmenu

I have a combobox and a table. Combobox have two items they are type1 and type2. When i select type1 from combo then table contextmenu shows "type1 menu" and When i select type2 from combo then table contextmenu shows "type2 menu". How to do this figure out?
Here is my experiment Code.... But its not work correctly..!

```
    import java.util.Arrays;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TableViewSample extends Application {

    private final TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
    private final ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
        );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        final Label label = new Label("Right Click a table Row");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        combo.getItems().setAll("Type1","Type2");
        combo.getSelectionModel().select(0);

        table.setEditable(true);

        //----------------------- Add table column ------------------------------//
        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> emailCol = new TableColumn<>("Email");
        emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("email"));

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(Arrays.asList(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol));

        setTableMenu(0);  // You Can Comment This //

        combo.setOnAction(event -> {
            setTableMenu(combo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
        });

        //-------------------------- Final Works ------------------------------//
        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, combo, table);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    //---------- Set What ContextMenu according to the combobox -----------//
    private void setTableMenu(int selectedIndex) {
         table.setRowFactory((TableView<Person> tableView) -> {
            final TableRow<Person> row = new TableRow<>();
            switch(selectedIndex){
                case 0:
                    final ContextMenu contextMenu1 = new ContextMenu();
                    final MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem("Type1 menu");
                    item1.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                        System.out.println("Type 1 menu selected");
                    });
                    contextMenu1.getItems().add(item1);

                    // Set context menu on row, but use a binding to make it only show for non-empty rows:
                    row.contextMenuProperty().bind(
                            Bindings.when(row.emptyProperty())
                            .then((ContextMenu) null)
                            .otherwise(contextMenu1)
                    );
                    break;
                 case 1:
                     final ContextMenu contextMenu2 = new ContextMenu();
                     final MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("Type2 menu");
                     item2.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                         System.out.println("Type 2 menu selected");
                     });
                     contextMenu2.getItems().add(item2);

                     // Set context menu on row, but use a binding to make it only show for non-empty rows:
                     row.contextMenuProperty().bind(
                             Bindings.when(row.emptyProperty())
                             .then((ContextMenu) null)
                             .otherwise(contextMenu2)
                     );
             }                     
            return row ;  
        });  
    }


    public static class Person {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty email;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String fName) {
            email.set(fName);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: well, I think it's a bug - tableView should recreate all rows/cells on setting new factories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `rowFactory` won't update the `TableRow`s. The rows will still be the ones created by the initial `rowFactory` and the type of context menu is decided when the row is created and is never changed.

You could however prepare the `ContextMenu` just before it's shown and modify it according to the state of the `ComboBox`:

```
// in start method
table.setRowFactory((TableView<Person> tableView) -> {
    final TableRow<Person> row = new TableRow<>();
    final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

    final MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem("Type1 menu");
    item1.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        System.out.println("Type 1 menu selected");
    });

    contextMenu.getItems().add(item1);

    final MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("Type2 menu");
    item2.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        System.out.println("Type 2 menu selected");
    });

    row.contextMenuProperty().bind(
            Bindings.when(row.emptyProperty())
            .then((ContextMenu) null)
            .otherwise(contextMenu)
    );

    row.setOnContextMenuRequested(evt -> {
        // update menu when requested
        switch (combo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()) {
            case 0:
                contextMenu.getItems().setAll(item1);
                break;
            case 1:
                contextMenu.getItems().setAll(item2);
                break;
        }
    });

    return row;
});

/*setTableMenu(0);

combo.setOnAction(event -> {
    setTableMenu(combo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
});*/
```

Alternatively you could also use the same `ContextMenu` for all rows and just modify that on a change in the `ComboBox`:

```
// in start method
final MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem("Type1 menu");
item1.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    System.out.println("Type 1 menu selected");
});

final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu(item1);

final MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("Type2 menu");
item2.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    System.out.println("Type 2 menu selected");
});

combo.setOnAction(evt -> {
    switch (combo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()) {
        case 0:
            contextMenu.getItems().setAll(item1);
            break;
        case 1:
            contextMenu.getItems().setAll(item2);
            break;
    }
});

table.setRowFactory((TableView<Person> tableView) -> {
    final TableRow<Person> row = new TableRow<>();

    row.contextMenuProperty().bind(
            Bindings.when(row.emptyProperty())
            .then((ContextMenu) null)
            .otherwise(contextMenu)
    );

    return row;
});

/*setTableMenu(0);

combo.setOnAction(event -> {
    setTableMenu(combo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
});*/
```

Comment: hmmm .. not recreating the rows/cells on setting a row/cellFactory looks like a bug to me

Comment: It would just take a call to `refresh`, to recreate the rows, but I decided against this, since it's just unnecessary to recreate the rows just to modify the context menu...

Comment: yeah, never-ever use refresh ... that's evil api and meant exclusively for the extremely rare case that nothing else helps. And it's definitely a bug: setting a cellFactory (vs. a rowFactory) does update the cells as expected.

Comment: hmm ... seems like the binding stands in the way: plain setting the contextMenu looks fine for a rowFactory ... no idea why, though

Comment: no, it's not the binding - in my test, I set a new cellFactory at the same time as the rowFactory, then the new rowFactory is created with the new ContextMenu, for both binding and manual setting. Now back to real work ;-)

Comment: Beware: this answer is hacking around a bug - DO NOT use as a general approach, it introduces way too much coupling between otherwise independent parts of the UI

Comment: @kleopatra: Huh? I wouldn't call replacing the context menu one way or the other independent. Especially in the second approach it seems like you cannot do it with less coupling: One way or the other you have to modify the existing context menu or replace it with a new one... The only improvement I'd probably come up with is replacing the `ComboBox` items and using the strategy pattern to modify the `ContextMenu`...

Comment: there is no replacing of contextMenus in the question, they are newly created along with the cells ;-) The issue is not sharing contextMenus as such, the issue is sharing them with _cells_ - we never know when/how they are re-used or discarded. Any coupling into them is brittle (probably not in this case) and if it goes wrong, hard to debug. So better avoid it at all: create and configure a cell once in the factory, then forget it exists.